# How to store the data in Json pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have data in store in excel sheet. Now i want to store the data in json format. I use different method like `df.to_json(orient=’records’)  df.to_json(orient=’index’)` but I'm not getting the result I want. below is the example

```
name    First_month_salary  Second_month_salary third_month_salary  fourth_month_salary
abc           15000                25000              14444                60000
fgh           15000                25000              14444                60000
xyz           15000                25000              14444                60000
```

I want output in the following format:

```
abc : [{"value1" : "1500" , "value1.1" : "1500" ,"value1.2" : "1500"  }, {"value2" : "25000" , "value2.1" : "25000" , "value2.2" : "25000" } , {"value3" : "14444" , "value3.1" : "14444"  , "value3.2" : "14444"}, {"value4" : "60000" , "value4.1" : "60000" , "value4.2" : "60000"}]
fgh : [{"value1" : "1500" , "value1.1" : "1500" ,"value1.2" : "1500"  }, {"value2" : "25000" , "value2.1" : "25000" , "value2.2" : "25000" } , {"value3" : "14444" , "value3.1" : "14444"  , "value3.2" : "14444"}, {"value4" : "60000" , "value4.1" : "60000" , "value4.2" : "60000"}]
xyz : [{"value1" : "1500" , "value1.1" : "1500" ,"value1.2" : "1500"  }, {"value2" : "25000" , "value2.1" : "25000" , "value2.2" : "25000" } , {"value3" : "14444" , "value3.1" : "14444"  , "value3.2" : "14444"}, {"value4" : "60000" , "value4.1" : "60000" , "value4.2" : "60000"}]
```

when I convert it. I get the output like this:

```
[{"name" : "abc" ,  {"First_month_salary" :"1500" ,"second_month_salary" : "25000", "third_month_salary" :"14444", "fourth_month_salary" : "60000"},
{"name" : "fgh" , {"First_month_salary" :"1500" ,"second_month_salary" : "25000", "third_month_salary" :"14444", "fourth_month_salary" : "60000"},
{"name" : "xyz" , {"First_month_salary" :"1500" ,"second_month_salary" : "25000", "third_month_salary" :"14444", "fourth_month_salary" : "60000"}]
```

all i want I don't need the column name in my output

Comment: That desired format doesn't look like a JSON.

Comment: Yes because there is no key -> value structure

Comment: bro I do some changes in it. just look the question again. you will get it

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is not valid JSON, you can paste it into an online parser yourself to confirm.

If I had to guess, it looks like you want a dict where the keys are the value of 'name' and the values are a list of salaries.

```
{'abc': [1500 ,25000, 14444, 60000],
...
}
```

If that is what you are looking for, then you could do as follows:

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'sal1': [10, 20, 30], 'sal2': [100, 200, 300], 'sal3': [1000, 2000, 3000]})

d = {}
for idx, row in df.set_index('Name').iterrows():
    d[idx] = row.values.tolist()
```

The output of d would be

```
{'abc': [10, 100, 1000], 'def': [20, 200, 2000], 'ghi': [30, 300, 3000]}
```

and then, if needed, you can write it to a file using the `json` module.